# string.Format Input string was not in correct format for string with curly brackets already as part of the format C#

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to format a `Json` input to a `JSON RPC`. For example, the `JSON` am goint to post is as following,

```
"{"filter":{ "Ids": [123, 124], "Types":["EMPLOYEE"]}}"
```

which I expect to return users with id 123, 124 and of type EMPLOYEE. But for the Ids parameter, I want to may it dynamic so that I can set the value in my C# calling method like the following

```
string.Format("{\"filter\":{ \"Ids\": [{0}], \"Types\":[\"EMPLOYEE\"]}}", "123, 124");
```

when doing so, I get the format exception `"Input string was not in correct format"`....

I know, I can build up the string using `string.concat` or `string builder`. Am just curious, if there is any solution to overcome this `string.format` exception in the event when a string has `curly brackets` (am assuming this is the cause of the exception) already.

Comment: `{` needs to be escaped if you want to use it literally.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have to escape "{" and "}"-chars by using "{{" resp. "}}".

See "Escaping Braces" in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx.